# SQLAlchemy one-to-many without the child table having a primary key

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy, ddl

Is it possible to create a table without a primary key in SQLAlchemy? The relationship I want to define is as follows:

```
class TPost(Base):
  __tablename__ = "forum_post"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("forum_topic.id"))
  index = Column(Integer)
  page = Column(Integer)
  user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("forum_user.id"))
  posted_at = Column(DateTime)
  post_text = Column(String)
  has_quotes = Column(Boolean)
  quotes = relationship("TQuote")

class TQuote(Base):
  __tablename__ = "forum_quotes"
  id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("forum_post.id"))
  is_direct = Column(Boolean)
  quoted_text = Column(String)
  quoted_id = Column(Integer)
```

As you can see I don't really need a primary key, and I don't intend to extend the `Quote` relationship in the future.

My problem specifically is represented by this error message :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|TQuote|forum_quotes 
could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'forum_quotes'
```

**edit :** 
The `(id,quoted_id)` pair is unique, and it present for the majority of the data, however when the quote is not direct(and doesn't have a quoted_id in that case), I inline the quoted text directly into the quote relationship. I could use a dual table approach (where the indrect quotes have a table with a primary key), but I'd really rather implement this as a single one-to-many relationship. I don't want to have to do more than a single join.

**edit 2:**

I'll number the quotes and use the foreign-key + app generated number as a pkey, still annoying tho. Now to figure out the syntax.

**edit 3:**

Solved the problem as outlined in edit 2. Quite annoyed with sql alchemy since it has all the information it needs to implement the relatioship even when modelling the data at a high level. I understand the reasons why Sql Alchemy wants to have a primary key (makes the orm easier to implement).

I am beginning to question why I am using Sql Alchemy, without it I could implement one way UPSERT or CREATE_IF_NOT_EXIST asynchronous operations using psycopg2. ORM's really need to catch up.

Comment: why are you trying to resist using one? is it size? cleanness of the data model? other reason?

Comment: Cleanness primarily. But if you think about it incrementing a seeializer is another database operation.

Comment: Yes, but even if you do not define a PK, the database will still keep one internally, and will run the same incremenation operation. Usage of PKs is really well optimized on all RDBMSs. Google for "surrogate primary keys", and you might come to the conclusion that having the PK (even if you do not need it) is in fact the most simple to model RDBs.  But most importantly, there is nothing you save by not having it. For performance reasons you might want to define CLUSTED index on (id, quoted_id) columns instead of PK column if you mostly search on (id, quoted_id).

Comment: problem is the id-quoted id pair is only available for forum posts which quote using the "reply to this post" button, you can put unlinked quotes in as well. For those, a quoted-id is not available. So my only choice is to use a serialized (auto-incrementing) id, or to split the quote types into two tables.

Comment: I guess by these comments it is implied that sql alchemy cannot deal with tables without primary keys ? It's a shame because my last task was a multi-million entry dataset comprising of 10 gigabytes of loaded data. every byte counts in those situations.

Comment: As mentioned earlier (even though I am not 100% sure of it, so you should ask SQL admins), even if you do not create a PK, there will be some identifier created internally anyways which will occupy the space anyways. *Also you mentioned that **cleanness** is the primary concert, and now it is size.* I am wondering if you are trying to squeeze optimization in a wrong place here. But please post the outcome of your research and the decision. Thanks.

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of the idea that a table can be useful without a primary key.  Primary keys are the way you identify *which row*, in a way that is very similar to the notion of object identity in OOP.  The fact that sqlalchemy enforces this world view is, IMNSHO, good.  Are you confusing the idea of primary key (which could, for example, include all of the rows in the table) with a surrogate key (which is not a real world attribute, usually a small integer generated by a database primitive)?

Comment: 4 bytes isn't small when you have multiple million entries, in this case I do not. I don't like paying for what I do not need.

Comment: Another way to put TokenMacGuy's point is: It is not even a __table__ in a relational database if it doesn't have a primary key.  In that case it would be something more like a spreadsheet.  But not even that, because a spreadsheet does have a primary key: the row number.

There is a simple yes-or-no question that differentiates this: Would you allow rows in the table that are exact duplicates of each other?  If you would not, you need SOME kind of primary key.  Furthermore, if you __would__ allow multiple rows to be exact duplicates of each other, what would that even mean to your app?

Comment: I believe in relational theory, I got a first in every data modeling / database relational theory in every course I took. However, the nature of the data demands how closely one follows relational purity. When you can predict the nature of the data and how you will query it, than you have every right to ignore elements of relational theory. In this case there is VERY small chance of duplicates, and duplicates do not matter. Every DB I know off (mysql, postgres, sql server) does tables without pkey's, and there is obviously a reason for this.

Comment: Furthermore, the option I chose, implicitly sorts the data in a more performant manner than if I had given it a traditional sequenced primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional column to give the quotes a index, and then add make a composite key of this new column + the foreign key.

Answer (score 14):

I am assuming @TokenMacGuy is right, and you really are confusing the notions of `PrimaryKey`, and a `surrogate key`. In which case the answer to your question is:

- **NO**, SA does not support tables (and therefore relations to tables) without a primary key
- and **NO**, you do not need to create a surrogate key for each table for the purpose of serving as a `primary key`. You can define a PK using any combination of columns with are unique.

See the code below for an example:

```
class TPost(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'forum_post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    post_text = Column(String)
    quotes = relationship("TQuote", backref="post")

class TQuote(Base):
    __tablename__ = "forum_quotes"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("forum_post.id"))
    is_direct = Column(Boolean)
    quoted_text = Column(String)
    quoted_id = Column(Integer) 
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint(id, quoted_id),)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, and I have +1'd. `(id,quoted_id)` = candidate if and only if id_direct = true (75% of the data falls into this category). So, in order to have a candidate key for all of the data I am using a new field + `id` new field is an app generated incremented number. So update your post and I will accept <3

Comment: I think I answered the question as it was asked, and do not see how I can improve it. You are free to accept it (or not) with an additional comment (which you posted) on how you solved the issue. Or you may add your own solution, and accept it for completeness.